# I want to display current date in my language with PHP

Tags: php, function, date

I am using this PHP Function, which is working great:

```
<?php echo date('l, d F Y'); ?>
```

Today, it outputs `Tuesday, 19 November 2013`, but I want it to be in my language. Is there a way I can set variables for each day of the week, and each month of the year, in my language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the [setlocale()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) and [strftime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) functions instead of date().

Answer (score -1):

$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);